# filter a dataframe based on a specific value for each category in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, outliers

I have a dataframe

```
df = url   browser     loadtime
      A     safari      1500
      A     safari      1650
      A     Chrome      2800
      B     IE          3150
      B     safari      3300
      C     Chrome      2650
      .      .            .
      .      .            .
```

I need to compute the upper outlier of the load time per app using the 3 QI rule of thumb and then filter df keeping only rows where for each app, loadtime is less than the upper outlier for this same app.

This is how I proceed.

1. I compute the upper outlier using the 3QI rule of thumb

```
def upper_outlier(x):
    return np.percentile(x, 75) + 3*(np.percentile(x,75)-np.percentile(x,25))

## Find the upper outlier threshold per app
df_grouped = df.groupby("app")['loadtime'].agg([('upper_outlier', lambda x : upper_outlier(x))])
```

This way for each app I have the corresponding upper outlier

2. I filter `df` using `df_grouped`

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame()
for app in df.app.unique():
    df_new = pd.concat([df_new,df.loc[(df.app==app)&(df.loadtime<df_grouped.loc[app, 'upper_outlier'])]], axis = 0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The for loop takes long as I have a lot of data. Is there a cleaner pythonic way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to merge your calculation with the original dataframe

```
df_grouped = df.groupby("app")['loadtime'].agg([('upper_outlier', lambda x : upper_outlier(x))]).reset_index()

dfmerged = df.merge(df_grouped, on = 'app', how = 'left')
```

and then filter

```
dfmerged[dfmerged.loadtime<dfmerged.upper_outlier]
```

Not sure if this is more efficient, but seems more straight forward.

Comment: It's definitely more straight forward. It runs 10 times faster than the original! Thanks